# Spark: Is there a way to use resources in each of the local machine where is distributed?

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing

I have to admit that I don't know how to formulate properly a title question for this (any help is appreciated), but I'll try to be more clear here:

I would like to distribute a task with Spark, but I would like to use exclusively some resources. There are no restrictions on the order of the dataset processed, but I wish that every batch distributed and analysed in different nodes of the clusters use different resources.

I will give an example that, hopefully, will make the question clearer:

Immagine I have to analyse 10MLN text messages for a task of sentiment analysis. The sentiment analysis is provided by a Webserver that is able to analyse a batch of 100 messages in 100ms via API accessible with credentials. Since I don't want to waste weeks for analyse them all, the idea is to distribute the task. But I cannot distribute the SAME credential because I would incur in RateLimit, or overload. 
The desirable solution would be to use ONE credential per partition in Spark, or per node. How can I do that given that the credentials might change, so they are not fixed for nodes?

Comment: That sounds like a job for `mapPartitions*`, so maybe you could just use use `WithIndex` version or retrieve task context and assign unique thread local credentials based on that?